# Home Improvement swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 950 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://diy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Home Improvement Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Home Improvement Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: diy.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: diy.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Curses!  48 rep points shy :)

Comment: Link to the product sizing page (under product specs) if you can't cut/paste the link in the form: http://www.hanesprintables.com/catalog/CatalogProduct.aspx?ProductID=4980

Comment: Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Cool stuff, be happy to wear that shirt to my favorite building materials suppliers.  They like the business cards you sent me.  I have handed out a bunch, and will have them out at my next public home show as well.  Jeff and crew are great folks.  Thanks, Steve

PS: Don't forget to send me a new Vette, just in case you got one hanging around. Need something to put the stickers on!

Comment: Hard to fit the toolbox in a Vette...but I'm sure you'll manage somehow...

Answer (score 0):

The email i got had incorrect links- going to photo.stack exchange users.. i could not click on the sizes and i found it very suspicious even running on google docs? Its easy to make a php submit form on diy.stackexchange somewhere.. You could have just asked a SU / SO Moderator- its 5 minute job.

Comment: hmm, sorry about that -- minor typo in one part of the HTML form header that I have now corrected. The email must have been *mostly* correct, as there are values in the diy.se google docs spreadsheet ... if the link to the google docs spreadsheet in the email was bad, nobody could fill out the form!

Comment: Yea - Cool- before when I pressed the link to here it said page not found also so I was a bit confused. Using chrome- I still cant click (nor copy) the sizing measurements link. PS Thanks for the fantastic gifts offer! Great job. PSS Next time you need some webpage design i can do some work for DIY pro bono. -Peter

Comment: see http://www.hanesprintables.com/catalog/CatalogProduct.aspx?ProductID=4980 then click "product specs" on the sidebar..

Comment: Good point, come to think of it @JeffAtwood why didn't you just do this whole site in php?  You like php right?

Comment: @mike we will take that under advisement :)